# SQL Query fetching wrong rows

Tags: mysql

If you check out this page, this is my schema and query which **correctly** fetches what I want (Team Score).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90a69/1

Problem with my query is, if a user is part of multiple teams (in different competitions) - the query also fetches those rows.

Check out the last INSERT in the schema, I added the same user (userid 1) to a different competition (to the one we use in the WHERE clause) - and it pulls in that team as the third row. Which I don't want.

To clarify, I do not want to fetch the third row - because the competitionId does not match the one specified in the WHERE clause.

Help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to do if user is part of multiple teams? Select one of them or select all of them in one column?

Comment: So I only want to select the teams for the competitionId I specify in the WHERE clause.

Comment: To clarify, A user will only be part of one team PER competition - but a user can be active in MANY competitions.

Comment: From what I can see all the competition ID's are the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you named the wrong table for your competition id

```
WHERE a.competitionId = '52934d4576fe4'
```

should be

```
WHERE t.competitionId = '52934d4576fe4'
```

Comment: So I solved it using

WHERE a.competitionId = '$compId'
AND t.competitionId = '$compId'

:)